# Div and H2 appearing in same line

Tags: html, css

I currently have the following:

`HTML`

```
<body>

<h1>Web Services</h1>


<div id="wrap">

    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="welcome.jsp">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="importMarketData.jsp">Service A</a></li>
        <li><a href="downloadFile.jsp">Service B</a></li>
        <li><a href="summaryMarket.jsp">Service C</a></li>
        <li><a href="currencyMarketData.jsp">Service D</a></li>      
   </ul> 
</div>

<h2>Overview</h2>

<div class="textParagraph">
    <p>
        The Web Services listed on this site allow users to retrieve, alter and summarize information contained with a "Market Data File". 
        A Market Data File contains data about financial instruments. 
    </p>
    <p>
        Please click on the links above for more information about our services and have a trial run.
    </p>
</div>
```

`CSS`

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

body {
font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;    
width: 900px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;

}


/* Begin Navigation Bar Styling */
#nav {

  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 3em 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-left:1px solid #ccc; }
  #nav li {float: left;}
  #nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #069;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc; }
  #nav li a:hover {
  color: #c00;
  background-color: #fff; }
  /* End navigation bar styling. */

  /* This is just styling for this specific page. */
  #wrap {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #fff; }   


h1 {

text-align:center; 

}

h2 {

text-align:center;

}
```

This is what it looks like at the moment.

[image]

The navigation bar should also be aligned in the center. I got the code for the navigation bar from some site.

`Overview` should be on the next line and centered with `WebServices`.

How can I got about achieving this? I don't understand why the `<div>` and `<h2>` are appearing on the same line..

Comment: Providing a jsBin or CodePen would help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

Change `#nav` to something like this.

```
#nav {
  margin: 0 0 3em 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-left:1px solid #ccc; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`#wrap` needs some help to know that it has to contain it's floated children; you can easily do this by adding an `overflow: auto;`:

```
#wrap {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #fff; 
    overflow: auto;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

`zoom` is a IE-specific rule, there to help trigger hasLayout in older versions.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have `#nav { float: left }` you will need to add a clear after the it. You may do this will a utility class of `.clear` on the h2.

```
.clear {
     clear: both;
 }
```

Or, just add `clear: both` to the h2 element.

Answer (score 0):

Your navbar is floated; you need to apply `clear: left;` to the h2 element to force it to appear below the navbar. If you want everything centered, remove the `float: left` and add `text-align: center` to your code.

Answer (score 0):

check the demo

```
#wrap {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background-color: #fff;
float: left;
border: 1px solid #f00;
width: 100%;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/uotxtuo5/)

Answer (score 0):

add this to your wrap

```
class="clearfix"
```

then in css add this

```
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

You have floated element in your wrap thus making your wrap height zero, you need clearfix to adjust the wrap height according to the floated element

Answer (score 0):

change wrap css to :

```
#wrap {
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
     }
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/utfp20sp/